# Android SDK's Button is replaced by MaterialButton when I changed my App Theme to a Material Theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, material-design, androidx

When I changed my app's theme to a Material theme (i.e. one of the themes available in the `Theme.MaterialComponents.*` package) in order to use the [MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/) component, I have no longer been able to use Android SDK's `Button` when I simply use `<Button>` tag in my layout files. When I click the `<Button>` tag, Android Studio navigates me to `android.widget.Button` class. But when I click the `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` tag, Android Studio navigates me to `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` class. So the question is may I ***safely*** use the `<Button>` tag instead of `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "safely"? The `LayoutInflater` used by the Material Components will create `MaterialButton` objects when you use `<Button>` elements, just as the AppCompat `LayoutInflater` would create an `AppCompatButton` for your `<Button>`. So, what is your definition of "safely"?

Comment: I mean does the usage of `<Button>` tag exactly the same with the other one? The examples in the official documentation and some others as well explicitly use `<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>` tag instead of `<Button>` tag despite the theme is already updated to a Material theme used by Material Components.

Comment: It will not be exactly the same, in that Material Components (and AppCompat) support additional attributes (e.g., prefixed with `app`).

Comment: You may post this comment as an answer, so I will be able to mark it as the answer to the question in order to let others directly identify the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean does the usage of  tag exactly the same with the other one?

On the whole, yes. The Material Components `LayoutInflater` may support additional `app:`-prefixed attributes, just as AppCompat does. And, it is possible that some attributes that an ordinary `Button` honors will be ignored by Material Components. But your app should not crash just because you use `<Button>` for the element.